# Links don't work

Tags: css, hyperlink, z-index

The problem is, the links in the main menu don't work, you can hover on them and see the address that it links to, but when you click them nothing happens.

I'm assuming it's something to do with the css.

I tried deleting all the z-index to see if it's something to do with them(in case it was behind something and you couldn't actually click them), I switched positionings around, nothing works.

Here is a link to the demo site.
http://tinyurl.com/nlmw2sg

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I found the answer. I was using this script for the sticky menu http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint and I just had to delete this line

```
e.preventDefault();
```

from it so that the page will jump to where the link points to.

Comment: Why are you using SMINT if you just want the links to work normally? Instead of editing SMINT code and removing e.preventDefault(); (which is what it SHOULD do to prevent your links from working and using the scrollTop() method instead), if you don't need SMINT, just remove the library from your web page.

Comment: I need it for the menu to be sticky, so that when you scroll down the page, the menu comes along :)

Comment: You can do that with some simple CSS, in fact that is what I suggest. No need to add an ENTIRE jQuery library just for a sticky menu.. And no need to use jQuery to make a sticky menu... The way SMINT does it, every time you scroll the window, SMINT makes a jQuery call to stick the header to the top of the page. Sounds poor in performance compared to just using pure CSS.

Comment: you are right about the sticky menu, it's just that I've never used one before and I didn't knew you can make one using just CSS, but it's actually really easy, just made the position: fixed; :) Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

It's not the CSS.

SMINT is returning this error every time you click a link:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null`

Looking at smint.js this is the line of code it is complaining about:

`var goTo =  $('div.'+ id).offset().top -selectorHeight;`

Which means that `$('div.'+ id)` is not selecting anything.

This tells me that you're not formatting your HTML the way SMINT needs you to. You need to follow their `<div>` and `**class**` structure.